How to make pg_dump exporting only a specific schema without "public"?
I faced a weird issue with Postgres (15.4). I want to pg_dump only a specific schema:
pg_dump --data-only --schema=vectors -v

and figured out that the dump contains also all tables from my public-schema. The verbose-switch also shows that tables from the public-schema will be exported as well.
There is NO reference in my vectors-schema via Foreign key or similar things to the public schema.
The only candidate of a reference is that the vectors-schema contains tables that uses the vector-type provided by the pgvectors-extension, with is used here as "public.vector" when it comes to address the datatype of a corresponding column.
Why is pg_dump still dumping all tables from my public-schema and how can I avoid that?

I cannot reproduce that. For me (on PostgreSQL v17), it works as expected, and only the tables from that schema are dumped.

15.4 is a year out of date, current version is 15.8.  Anyway, I can't reproduce the issue. --schema works as expected on 15.4.

I was able to resolve my issue by combining the --schema option with the -t switch to select specific table names within my schema. This allowed me to limit the export to just the data I needed from a specific schema, while excluding others. Here's how I did it:
pg_dump --data-only --schema=vectors -t 'vectors.embeddings*' -v

Explanation:

--schema=vectors: This option limits the dump to only the vectors schema.
-t 'vectors.embeddings*': This switch allows me to specify a table name pattern, dumping only the tables that match vectors.embeddings*.
--data-only: Ensures that only data (and not the schema) is dumped.
-v: Enables verbose output to monitor progress.

By using the -t option, I was able to select only the tables I wanted to dump within the schema, which solved the problem of exporting unnecessary data.

The problem described in the question is not reproducible, so I don't how there can be an answer to it.
